# Constructing an $L^2$ space on the unit ring $\mathcal{S^1}$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces

**Revised Question:**

Starting with $L^2[0,2\pi]$, does the canonical map $$[0,2\pi)\ni\theta\mapsto e^{i\theta}\in\mathcal{S^1}$$(with functions going across in the obvious way) turn $L^2[\mathcal{S^1}]$ into a bona fide Hilbert space?

In particular, does the difference in topology between $[0,2\pi]$ and ${S^1}$ have any nasty implications?

**Original Question:**

Is the Hilbert Space of $L^2$ functions on $[0,2\pi]$ with $f(0)=f(2\pi)$ equivalent to a Hilbert Space of $L^2$ functions defined on the unit ring $\mathcal{S^1}$? Can I even construct the latter?

The reason I ask is that I'm uncertain whether the difference in the measure and topologies between $[0,2\pi]$ and $\mathcal{S^1}$ 'bubbles' its way up into functional analytic results.

**Note**: The boundary condition given is shorthand for: "The set of equivalence classes of Lebesgue square measurable functions (modulo sets of measure zero) containing a continuous member satisfying the given boundary condition".

Comment: If you talk about $L^2$ functions, then the formula $f(0)=f(2\pi)$ has little sense - integrable functions do not have values at points.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy This is a common shorthand for "The set of equivalence classes of Lebesgue square measurable functions (modulo sets of measure zero) containing a continuous member satisfying the given boundary condition".

Comment: $L^2([0,2\pi])$ is clearly isomorphic to the space of $2 \pi$ periodic functions which are $L^2$ on any interval $[a,a+2\pi]$, and $f(0) = f(2\pi)$ doesn't mean so much, for example with $f(x) = \frac{x}{2 \pi} -\lfloor \frac{x}{2 \pi} \rfloor$ or $g(x) = (\frac{x}{2 \pi} -\lfloor \frac{x}{2 \pi} \rfloor)^{-1/3}$ how do you define those boundary values ?

Comment: If a function is continuous on $[0,2\pi]$, then necessarily it is an (square-)integrable function. Hence your description just looks like a $C([0,2\pi])$ with boundary conditions.

Comment: @user1952009 Yes, all Hilbert spaces of a given dimension (and field) are isomorphic to each other. They don't have to look similar. My real question is whether I can rigorously set up a Hilbert Space directly on the ring, rather than on an interval. The ring requires a different measure and topology and I'm not sure if/how to set up my L2 space on it.

Comment: @PhysicsFootnotes I certainly hope you're not trying to demand all your $L^2$ functions have a continuous representative! That's just $C(S^1, \Bbb R)$ with the $L^2$ topology, which is not even a little complete. There is a natural isomorphism $L^2(S^1) \to L^2([0,2\pi])$ given by precomposing with the exponential $[0,2\pi] \to S^1$. This is an isomorphism no matter what way you choose to define $L^2(S^1)$.

Comment: No here I meant isomorphic as normed spaces of functions, simply consider the "$2\pi$-periodize" operator, sending any function of $L^2([0,2\pi])$ to a $2\pi$ periodic function, and rename the variable $x$ for obtaining a function of $L^2(S^1)$. (Try with one of the examples I wrote for understanding what I mean)

Comment: @MikeMiller You're right. I was accidentally thinking about operator domains that I will subsequently be interested in, as opposed to the whole space! Sorry about that. I really need to rephrase my question, because all I really want to understand is how to set up the right measure-theoretic gear to work on a ring instead of an interval.

Comment: @MikeMiller When I use the canonical isomorphism you suggest, I'm unclear whether the difference in topology between the two domains makes any difference to anything. I know that's a bit vague, because I'm confused about it myself!

Comment: For mathematics purposes, I think it would be better to refer to the "unit circle", rather than "unit ring", since "ring" has some other reserved-word senses. The circle $S^1$ is a quotient $S^1=\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ is also obviously a topological group with its own Haar (=invariant) measure, and is related to the usual measure on $\mathbb R$ by the compatibility $\int_{S^1} \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z}f(x+n)\;dx = \int_{\mathbb R} f(x)\;dx$ for compactly supported continuous $f$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$L^2$ spaces should not be sensitive to the topology or shape of whatever underlying space you're working with. Indeed, given a "manifold" (a generalization of circles and surfaces), one way of defining an $L^2$ space on it is to pick a chart $D^n \to M$, where $D$ is the unit disc, that is injective except at a set of measure zero, and then pull back functions to $D^n$; one says functions on $M$ are measurable if the pullback is measurable, $L^2$ if the pullback is $L^2$, etc.

Here is my favorite way of defining functions on a manifold $M$. The things you can integrate on manifolds aren't functions, they're [differential forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form); but we will hide this difficulty by picking a top-dimensional nonvanishing form $\omega$, and defining "$\int_M f$" $= \int_M f\omega$. For the circle, we're going to pick $\omega = d\theta$ (so that the integral looks like something you've seen before). Now I define $L^2(M)$ to be the *completion* of $C(M)$, the set of continuous functions on $M$, with respect to the $L^2$ norm $\|f\|^2 = \int_M f^2 \omega$. This does not exhibit $L^2(M)$ as an actual set of functions (modulo measure zero etc), but it does give a perfectly serviceable definition; I would say an $L^2$ function is just an element of this completion!

From this perspective, it is *completely clear* that $L^2(S^1)$ is the completion of $C_p([0,2\pi])$, where the subscript means I'm considering functions with $f(0) = f(2\pi)$. This is because there is a canonical isometry $C_p([0,2\pi]) \to C(S^1)$, the point being that $\int_{S^1} f^2 d\theta$ is the exact same thing as $\int_{[0,2\pi]} f^2 dx$ (just think of how the first term is defined in any way you've ever seen it defined). A similar argument shows that both of the definitions of $L^2(M)$ I gave are equivalent.

You could also go a straightforward route and say that a function on $M$ is measureable iff it's measureable in every chart, and if it's measurable, define $\int f$ by choosing a finite atlas of charts and a partition of unity with respect to this atlas and summing up the integrals of $\rho_\alpha f$ over each chart. But I find this aesthetically displeasing.

Comment: Thanks for this effort. I haven't digested all of it yet, but it looks great. Just one last thing if you don't mind. In the identification of these two L2 spaces, I've always been irritated by the fact that the interval space counts $0$ and $2\pi$ as separate points and so we don't have a perfect bijection between the domains. I know with a point having measure zero it doesn't matter, but what is the best way to tidy up that issue to make a genuine bijection?

Comment: @PhysicsFootnotes You could work with $L^2$ spaces on $[0,2\pi)$ instead, if you like, but I think you should try to move past being upset by the fact that we quotient out by the identification of functions that agree on a measure zero set. It's a part of life that we do that, so extraneous points *shouldn't* bother us. Indeed, the fact that we don't care about measure zero sets is probably why you *should* think that $L^2(S^1)$ and $L^2([0,2\pi])$ are "pretty much the same".

Comment: Yeah, but my problem with working on the half open interval is that later I want to define periodic functions on them, which I then pull back onto the ring. But maybe you're right, and I shouldn't lose sleep over it.

Comment: @PhysicsFootnotes The thing is that $L^2$ functions on the circle don't need to be in any sense "periodic". Consider the inverse to the exponential, discontinuous one point, $S^1 \to [0,2\pi)$. This is a perfectly good $L^2$ function! But the function on $[0,2\pi]$ it comes from does not look particularly periodic.

Comment: Sure, but I may want to start with a self-adjoint operator on the interval and its self-adjointness requires periodicity.

Answer (score 2):

Of course as Hilbert spaces $L^2(S^1)$ and $L^2\bigl([0,1]\bigr)$ are isomorphic, and you could also say that $L^2\bigl([0,1]\bigr)$ is the prime example of a Hilbert space arising from Lebesgue theory.

But note that $L^2(S^1)$ is one of the most important Hilbert spaces in the world, and there definitively is an essential difference between $L^2\bigl([0,1]\bigr)$ and $L^2(S^1)$ which has not been exposed so far: While $[0,1]$ is just a measure space the ground set $S^1$ carries additional structure, namely a transitive group of translations. It is not necessary to go into details here. We all have heard of Fourier theory. E.g., there is a famous theorem saying that any function $f\in L^2(S^1)$ is represented (meaning "equal to") almost everywhere by its Fourier series.

Comment: Could you at least outline your thoughts for future Math.SE visitors?

Comment: I also would be extremely keen to hear of any differences between these spaces Christian. It's hard to know (especially when you're new to this place) at what point you should be satisfied with the answer given.

Comment: Thanks for that Christian. Any idea how I can find a good solid treatment of $L^2(S^1)$? I know it's a famous space, but as far as I know it doesn't have a name, so I'm struggling to find any good articles/chapters devoted to it. Much appreciated!